# Data not filling in with Edit Profile form Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using the following line to fill in data into the form.

```
form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

However, no data fills into the form. I just get the empty form. Not sure what's going wrong. I have a profile html where the data from each user shows up, but the line above is not working on the edit page. The model is the default user model. Django version 2.2.3.

```
#views.py
def editprofile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            agree = form.save(commit=False)
            agree.save()
            args = {'form': form}
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST)
        args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'profile_edit.html', {'form':form})
```

Here is my forms.py:

```py
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    email = forms.CharField(label= 'Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(EditProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

[image]

template

```
{% block content %}

<h3> Please edit your profile here </h3>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button href="{% url 'profilepage' %}" type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

### Added urls.py

```
path('profile/', views.profile, name = 'profilepage'),
path('profile/edit/', views.editprofile, name = 'editprofile')
```

Comment: Can you add the template code as well? Have you set the form method to "POST"?

Comment: Added template. If there is anything else that I need to add, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding action to your form tag in template. 
Like this:

```
<form action= "{% url 'editprofile' %}" method="post">
```

'editprofile' is the url_name of your editprofile view. Also the `class Meta` and method `def save()` should be inside your `class EditProfileForm()` block.

Comment: This does not work for me. No button comes up to submit the form. The data does not pre-fill for the user.

Comment: can you show your urls.py? Also, why are you using `href` inside button tag?? It doesn't work. No need to use href in button just do this to submit your form: `<button type="submit" >Submit</button>`

Comment: And to pre-fill the form you need to give value for the pre existing data in your input tag `<input name="field_name" value="{{ field.value }}">` since you are using `{{ form.as_p }}` it doesn't work. Make your own form with inputs then give value to get the pre-fill data

Comment: The href is to move the form along to a new page, or it gets stuck on the edit_profile page. It actually works. What happens is that you fill out the form and then it redisplays the form as submitted, but with all the boxes blank again and with the ID of the submitted form.

Comment: is the submitted data being saved in the database?? and to move along to another page do it from your views.py using `return redirect('app_name:view_name_to_redirect')`  Do this after form.save

Comment: Yes, it's saved in the database - before and after the submit. I know that the profile information is created and saved at registration. Then, if you go to the profile page after submit, the new data is there.

Comment: Ok if the data is being saved what is the problem then??

Comment: The data will not pre-fill in the form like the picture denotes. It's just blank, even though there is data for that instance.

Comment: Ok you mean, after submitting the form you want to edit that same data and show what was previously entered in the form ?? use different functions in view to submit the initial form and to edit the data. You need to pass the id or slug in the editform view to know which instance data to be displayed

Comment: So the instance is entered at the top into the form with, form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user).  The user exists and the data exists in the DB. No error, but the data does not show up. When, I display the error in the profile page, I do {{ user.name }} in the template, so it displays individually.